# USe function on the homepage fo WordPress only

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show only 3 posts on the first page off the home page and then 6 posts for the following pages. For all internal pages I just want the usual 6 posts per page. I have this working but it is doing the across all pages of the website not just the home page. I have tried  is_front_page but that didn't help.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sk_query_offset', 3 );
function sk_query_offset( &$query ) {

    // Before anything else, make sure this is the right query...
    if ( $query->is_home() && is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    // First, define your desired offset...
    $offset = -3;

    // Next, determine how many posts per page you want (we'll use WordPress's settings)
    $ppp = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

    // Next, detect and handle pagination...
    if ( $query->is_paged ) {

        // Manually determine page query offset (offset + current page (minus one) x posts per page)
        $page_offset = $offset + ( ( $query->query_vars['paged']-1 ) * $ppp );

        // Apply adjust page offset
        $query->set( 'offset', $page_offset );

    }
    else {

        // This is the first page. Set a different number for posts per page
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $offset + $ppp );

    }
}

add_filter( 'found_posts', 'sk_adjust_offset_pagination', 1, 2 );
function sk_adjust_offset_pagination( $found_posts, $query ) {

    // Define our offset again...
    $offset = -6;

    // Ensure we're modifying the right query object...
    if ( $query->is_home() && is_main_query() ) {
        // Reduce WordPress's found_posts count by the offset...
        return $found_posts - $offset;
    }
    return $found_posts;
}
```

Here is the homepage: www.ninesixty.co.nz/alisonhehir
and here is an internal page: www.ninesixty.co.nz/alisonhehir/studio

Comment: `$query->is_home()` this condition are referring to front page as well. You can eliminate or can write condition to display posts

Comment: As I said above I have tried  is_front_page  but it still applies the function to all pages. Thanks for taking the time to reply though

Comment: is_front_page() won't work because pre_get_posts runs before WP_Query has been set up. However,  is_home() will work though but it's best to use the query variables.

Comment: Can you please explain or link me to a reference for this? Sorry I'm still trying to get my head around this WordPress stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show 3 posts on your home page and then whatever you have setup as posts per page on your site for the remaining pagination pages.   I tested it for other combinations and it still appears to work correctly.  The [ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function is important for pagination to ensure it adds an extra page if there is a remainder when calculating the total number of pages to show.  This will only work if your home page is setup to show latest posts.  If you want it to work with a static page it's a lot more involved as [documented](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214895/using-pre-get-posts-on-true-pages-and-static-front-pages/215027#215027) in this post.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sk_query_offset', 3 );

function sk_query_offset( &$query ) {

    $offset = 3;
    $ppp = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && ! $query->is_paged ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $offset );
        return;
    }

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_paged ) {

        if( $query->query_vars['paged'] == 2 ) {
            $page_offset = $offset;
        }
        else {
            $page_offset = $offset + ( ( $query->query_vars['paged'] - 2 ) * $ppp );
        }

        $query->set( 'offset', $page_offset );
    }
}

add_filter( 'found_posts', 'sk_adjust_offset_pagination', 1, 2 );

function sk_adjust_offset_pagination( $found_posts, $query ) {
    $ppp = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

    // We set this value in sk_query_offset
    $offset_ppp = $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'];

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && ! $query->is_paged ) {
        // This is important, we need to always round up to the highest integer for calculating the max number of pages.
        $max_pages = ceil( $found_posts / $ppp );

        return ( $offset_ppp * $max_pages );
    }

    return $found_posts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately this doesn't work at all. This shows 6 posts on the home page so is just showing the defaut functionality.

Comment: How is your home page setup?  I have mine setup to show blog posts and it shows only 3 posts, you might have it setup to show a static page so it would work differently.

Comment: Yes it is a static page. Is it not possible this way?

Comment: It's a little bit of work to get it done, WordPress has linked this solution on the pre_get_posts codex for your situation. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214895/using-pre-get-posts-on-true-pages-and-static-front-pages/215027#215027

Comment: I got this working now with a slight variation of the code above. Only problem it now only shows 3 posts o the first page in the backend/dashboard now too. Any ides on how to ensure it only works on the front end of the website?

Comment: @JoshJ use the conditional tag is_admin(); to check if the dashboard is being accessed.  If you could accept my answer that would be great :)